# install4j support for code signing MacOS console launchers that load dyld libraries via System.loadLibrary

Tags: java, macos, install4j, dyld, notarize

I have an issue with a MacOS folder DMG media file that I created with install4j 8.0.8.  If I code sign the package, everything gets signed correctly including my *.dyld files that reside in a lib/ directory.  Also, my GUI programs work fine and calls to System.loadLibrary() succeed and load the dyld files correctly.  However, my command-line programs that call the same Java code as my GUI programs fail when they get to the System.loadLibrary() call with this message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jhdf5 (Not found in java.library.path)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1745)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1697)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:591)
```

But, if I disable code signing when I build the media file for MacOS, which I do by passing disableSigning=true from Ant, both GUI and command-line programs work fine.

So possibly, I'm not understanding if I need to *do something extra* with the Java VM parameters when running a program from a console launcher versus a GUI launcher on MacOS (I'm running Big Sur).  Or is it just not possible to run console launchers in a code signed media file where dyld files are loaded on demand?  Maybe due to the fact that console launchers are implemented as scripts on MacOS.  The install4j 8 documentation doesn't seem to mention this nuance that I can find.

The directory structure of the installed files looks like this:

```
Peters-MacBook-Pro-16:CoastWatch Utilities Signed phollema$ ll
total 4224
drwxr-xr-x  10 phollema  admin      320  9 Apr 17:25 .
drwxrwxr-x  37 root      admin     1184  9 Apr 17:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  53 phollema  admin     1696  9 Apr 17:25 .install4j
drwxr-xr-x   3 phollema  admin       96  9 Apr 17:24 CoastWatch Utilities Uninstaller.app
drwxr-xr-x  25 phollema  admin      800  9 Apr 18:50 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 phollema  admin       96  9 Apr 17:24 data
drwxr-xr-x   8 phollema  admin      256  9 Apr 17:25 doc
drwxr-xr-x   3 phollema  admin       96  9 Apr 17:24 extensions
drwxr-xr-x   4 phollema  admin      128  9 Apr 17:25 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 phollema  admin  1608406  9 Apr 17:12 src.zip
Peters-MacBook-Pro-16:CoastWatch Utilities Signed phollema$ ll bin
total 624
drwxr-xr-x  25 phollema  admin    800  9 Apr 18:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 phollema  admin    320  9 Apr 17:25 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 phollema  admin   6148  9 Apr 18:50 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   3 phollema  admin     96  9 Apr 17:24 CoastWatch Data Analysis Tool.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 phollema  admin     96  9 Apr 17:24 CoastWatch Master Tool.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 phollema  admin     96  9 Apr 17:24 CoastWatch Status Tool.app
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14801  9 Apr 17:12 cwangles
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14803  9 Apr 17:12 cwautonav
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14829  9 Apr 17:12 cwcomposite
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14827  9 Apr 17:12 cwcoverage
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14805  9 Apr 17:12 cwdownload
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14801  9 Apr 17:12 cwexport
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14827  9 Apr 17:12 cwgraphics
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14789  9 Apr 17:12 cwgscript
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14823  9 Apr 17:12 cwimport
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14797  9 Apr 17:12 cwinfo
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14819  9 Apr 17:12 cwmath
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14805  9 Apr 17:12 cwnavigate
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14829  9 Apr 17:12 cwregister
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14831  9 Apr 17:12 cwregister2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14823  9 Apr 17:12 cwrender
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14801  9 Apr 17:12 cwsample
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14841  9 Apr 17:12 cwscript
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14799  9 Apr 17:12 cwstats
-rwxr-xr-x   1 phollema  admin  14763  9 Apr 17:12 hdatt
Peters-MacBook-Pro-16:CoastWatch Utilities Signed phollema$ ll lib/native/macosx_x86_64/
total 12544
drwxr-xr-x  4 phollema  admin      128  9 Apr 17:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 phollema  admin       96  9 Apr 17:25 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 phollema  admin  1748128  9 Apr 17:12 libjhdf.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 phollema  admin  3536000  9 Apr 17:12 libjhdf5.dylib
```

Also, the console launcher scripts contain a line that adds to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` like this:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$app_home/lib/native/macosx_x86_64:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

All of this works if I don't sign the media file, and the console launcher scripts are identical.

Comment: What are "my GUI programs" and "my command-line programs"?  Does everything reside in the same code-signed bundle?

Comment: Everything resides in the same base directory which was installed by the install4j installer.  I have a directory called bin/ which contains both GUI launchers (named ending in .app) and also console launchers (just bash scripts).  The launchers are not signed, but the DMG media file was signed and was notarized by Apple successfully, and the binaries inside the DMG and inside jars were all signed and notarized.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, but it would be good to get confirmation.  It seems that if I add `-Djava.library.path=$app_home/lib/native/macosx_x86_64` to the java command line in the console launcher scripts, they run fine. So even though the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set and exported, the java executable included by the signed install4j media file *doesn't* listen to the environment variable, but *does* listen to a command line parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notarization requires enabling the "Hardened runtime" which prevents the use of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` unless a specific entitlement is set for the launcher executable. As of install4j 9.0.1, entitlements can only be set for GUI launchers and not for the java executable of a bundled JRE which is what would be needed for command line launchers.

However, setting `-Djava.library.path` is a good solution and preferable to setting entitlements.